# How can be the report opened automatically when test finishes

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, package.json, cucumber-serenity

I am running Serenity-js with cucumber and Angular CLI.

I am using scripts in 'package.json' to execute the sequence of cleaning, testing and generating the report `"e2e2": "failsafe clean pretest protractor report"`.

```
 //package.json
  .............
   "scripts": {
            "ng": "ng",
            "start": "ng serve",
            "build": "ng build",
            "test": "ng test",
            "lint": "ng lint",
            "e2e": "ng e2e",
            "webdriver-update": "webdriver-manager update",
            "protractor": "protractor ./protractor.conf.js",
            "clean": "rimraf target",
            "pretest": "serenity update",
            "report": "serenity run",
            "e2e2": "failsafe clean pretest protractor report"
   ................
```

Everything works fine but I want the report located in `target/site/serenity/index.html`  to be opened automatically when the test finishes.

How can I complete my script sequence with this functionality?

Comment: how does your `protractor.conf.js` look like?

Comment: I don't think that protractor has anything to do with this. I want to extend my script with something like this: `  "e2e2": "failsafe clean pretest protractor report open-report" `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to open some url in a browser once your `e2e2` script finishes just use `&&` + `platform specific browser open command` in your `e2e2` npm script

**Windows**: `"e2e2": "failsafe clean pretest protractor report && start <full-path- to-your-report>"`

**Mac**: `"e2e2": "failsafe clean pretest protractor report && open <full-path-to-your-report>"`

**Linux**: `"e2e2": "failsafe clean pretest protractor report && xdg-open <full-path-to-your-report>"`

If you are looking for cross-platform solution you can use [opnen-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/open-cli)
`npm install --save-dev opnen-cli`

**Cross-platform**: `"e2e2": "failsafe clean pretest protractor report && opnen <full-path-to-your-report>"`

If you want you can create a separate script like `open-report` with any of the above that works for you best and then just do:
`"e2e2": "failsafe clean pretest protractor report && npm run open-report"`

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for the cross platform solution. Full path was not necessary and worked for me with

               `  "open-report": "opn target/site/serenity/index.html",
                   "e2e2": "failsafe clean pretest protractor report open-report" `

Comment: FYI `opn-cli` is deprecated, use [`open-cli`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/open-cli) instead.